# Counterexample to sequential edge-coloring algorithm?

Tags: coloring

There is an algorithm to find the edge-coloring of a graph:

[image]

This is supposedly a greedy algorithm, but is there a counter-example when this algorithm doesn't produce a minimum edge-coloring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: take for example a length-4 path where the edges are numbered $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_4$, $e_3$ in that order.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I see it depends on the labeling of the edges.